# About running .class files generated by JRuby

Tags: java, jruby

Have a Ruby script,

```
print "HELLO"
```

If you use

```
jrubyc script.rb
```

You get a .class file.

How do I execute this in my Java program? (so that it outputs "HELLO" to the console). I am using JRuby's complete JAR.

Answer (score 0):

thus you've probably setup "embedded" (if not check-out answers such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095744/embedding-jruby-in-java-code-using-rvm-jruby-install)) JRuby from Java e.g. (JSR 223 might be similar - just use `ScriptEngine.eval` to run Ruby code) :

```
ScriptingContainer scriptContainer = new ScriptingContainer(LocalContextScope.CONCURRENT);
scriptContainer.runScriptlet("load 'script.class'");
```

simply `load` the .class file **script.class** assuming it can be resolved from the class-path / work-dir (otherwise might need to tune the `LOAD_PATH` - really depends on your Java environment/scenario)

Comment: I mean, within my Java program. Sorry for the confusion.